# How i can make hole in objects in unity

Tags: unity

I need to have a hole in my objects and I don't want to use terrain.

I'd like to use an object and cut them out of another object, so that there is a hole in which the player could fall into; a 'game over' would happen.

[image]

Comment: Your road in Unity is just a Mesh, a FBX file. So open it up in 3dsMax, use the boolean functions to cut out your hole then import it back into Unity.

Comment: Do you need the hole to be created during game-play or can it be pre-processed directly in the road-mesh just like Jermiah Leslie suggested in the above comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the road is a static object you can boolean it in 3d max and re-import, if not you'll have to use a third party plugin ( since unity it self doesn't allow complex modeling )

Something like [MegaMesh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcsF_EhCVPI) would suit your purpose, also try this [project](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/boolean-mesh-project.227196/), found it when searching around

Comment: MegaMesh boolean feature has never been fully released and the project you link to is unfortunately offline.